# How to reset the Admin password in CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp-2.3

I forget the admin password in cakephp application. I tried to update the password column in users table under MySql PhpMyAdmin. But it doesn't works. I am using CakePHP version 2.3.7.

Comment: If a particular answer is helpful in solving your problem, mark it as "accepted" by clicking the little checkmark next to it. If your questions are receiving unhelpful answers, clarify what you're looking for or leave constructive comments on the answers explaining how they fall short.

Comment: Hai sry for the delay @savedario. I did as explain in below answers. I am newbie to Cake PHP and did the steps you mentions below and i have the string value. After that where can i apply; which column i need to paste that string to rest my admin password? and could you please mention any steps i need to follow mandatory? 

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The string should go in the password column of your user table for the row containing your admin user.

Answer (score 2):

By itself, CakePHP does not have an "Admin password".
If you are using the Auth component with the out-of-the-box password hashing, add this inside your AppController beforeRender() method:

```
debug(Security::hash('the-desired-password'));
```

and visit your home (publicly available) page.

The string displayed is the value to enter in the user table for the admin user.

Remember to remove the above line once it all works again.

Answer (score 2):

First you have to check encryption method you are using, Cakephp by default use SHA1

check write following code on any action that is accessible without login

```
App::uses('SimplePasswordHasher', 'Controller/Component/Auth');
$passwordHasher = new SimplePasswordHasher(array('hashType' => 'sha1'));
echo $passwordHasher->hash("mynewpassword")
```

Copy the above Password and update it to your database